# How to check if only one combination exists in a table for a give column value

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique

I have a Table which has 3 columns child, parent & Grandparent. The child column is the primary key. Multiple child can report to the same parent.

Currently, my table has 4 child reporting to same parent so I will have 4 rows in the table. Since the parent is same for all 4 child I expect the Grandparent should also be the same.

But for certain records, the Grand Parent values is different which is an issue and I would like to add a constraint or something to prevent that from happening.

For eg my table looks like below

```
Child | Parent | GrandParent |
10001 | 101    | 700         |
10002 | 101    | 700         |
10003 | 101    | 701         |
10004 | 101    | 700         |
```

The 4th child 10003 reports to the parent 101 but the grandParent is different which I want to prevent it from happening.

The usual unique key constraint on the combination Parent / GrandParent will not work as these two columns can have duplicate values. I cannot add a constraint for the three columns because it wont prevent the above from happening.

Could you please let me know how to achieve this? I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: Your table design violates Third Normal Form, because the non-candidate key `Parent` completely determines the attribute `GrandParent` (or, at least, it **should** - and where it fails to, you have exactly the problem you want to avoid). Usually this is solved by not having the `GrandParent` column in this table; instead, you need a different table where the `Parent, GrandParent` pairs are shown, each just once (with `Parent` as PK).

Comment: If you must have `GrandParent` in this table as well, you would still be best off with this additional, small table - then make `(Parent, GrandParent)` a unique key (it WILL be unique anyway, but make it a composite unique key) and make the same pair a foreign key in your three-column table. Not recommended, but surely better than what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.**

As said in the comments, the grandparent column is not necessary. The parent - grandparent relation is namely the same relation as child - parent.

Like:

```
select a.child, a.parent, b.parent 
from parentchild a
,    parentchild b 
where b.child = a.parent
```

**Option 2.**

If you however insists on having this table layout, you could define a before insert or update trigger on the table, that checks if there is a record in the table already with the **same** parent but **different** grandparent. If such a row is found, the trigger should fail and flag an error, else the record can be inserted or updated.

Example code for trigger:

```
create trigger parentchild_iu
before insert or update
on parentchild for each row
declare
v_count number;
begin
   select count(*) into v_count
   from   parentchild p
   where  p.parent = :new.parent
   and    p.grandparent != :new.grandparent;

   if v_count != 0 then
      raise_application_error("Parent/Grandparent combination invalid.");
   end if;
end;
```

**Option 3.**

And as 3rd option, you can seperate the table out into two tables: childparent and parentgranparent, and have the following query:

```
select a.child, a.parent, b.grandparent
from   childparent a
,      parentgrandparent b
where  a.parent = b.parent;
```

And in both tables define unique keys for both columns.

Comment: We don't know that the parent-grandparent relation is the same relation as child-parent (in which case they may be in the same table). The relation may very well be different. For example "child" may be town, "parent" may be state or region or province, and "grandparent" may be country. The two dependencies are of essentially different natures and they definitely require different tables.

Comment: Hi mathguy - Exactly. The town, state, country is a perfect example. I cannot have another table. I think has Rob mentioned I should go with trigger. But How to check for the same record exists with different parent in a trigger? Can you provide me a example?